# Connection between UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext and drawInrect

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uiimage, image-resizing

I have found the following code to resize an UIImage:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.image.size.width*0.25, self.image.size.height*0.25);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but there are some couple of things I don't understand.

First I'm trying to resize the original image to 25% of the original size - but this method resizes it to 50% of the original size. Why?

What is the connection between `drawInRect` and `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`. As I see it, the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` is overwriting the current image making the call to `drawInRect` redundant.

I would be grateful if someone could help me understand what's going on in details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first , because it's retina screen, you should set the scale to 1.0 , or it just x2

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1.0);
```

if you call **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext** , any paint work will result in the **Context** you specific

the **drawInRect** in your code paint the image to the context, it's not redundant

or you can remove it, you get a empty image

finally, you can get a merged UIImage from the context

```
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

just get a UIImage From What you have done(on context)

if you don't set the image back  , it's won't change anything

```
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks,
If I set the scale to 1.0 it works as expected on my iPhone with Retina, but what about devices without retina? Will they still see the picture resized to 50%?

Comment: scale to 1.0 means 100% of your screen resolution,  scale to 0.0 means depend on your device , if it's iphone 3gs or before . it's 100% , if it's iphone 4 or later , it's 200%

Comment: the official doc:  
The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.